# No symbols have been loaded - windows service and topshelf

Tags: c#, breakpoints, topshelf

I am trying to debug a windows service. It's running as a console application with Topshelf. The startup project runs fine in with breakpoints and everything but none of the referenced projects in the solution seem to load their symbols. All the .pdb files are in the respective bin-folders. And a copy of all the referenced .pdb files are also in the startup projects bin-folder. Everything builds/rebuilds when i press F5.

- It worked fine a few days ago and still works fine on all my colleagues PC's.
- I'm sure I'm running all projects in debug mode.
- I've cleaned, rebuilt and tried attaching to the process instead of just F5.
- I get the same behavior in both VS2017 and VS2015.
- I've deleted all the source code and redownloaded and even reinstalled all versions of VS.

None of the referenced projects show up in the Modules window. (* Actually. One of the referenced projects does show up sometimes, but I don't understand when/why. I can debug that project - when it shows up in the Modules window)

Answer (score 0):

Disable the debug option `Enable Just My Code` (Tools -> Options)

Be advised; turning this off will slow down start up time of the debugger since loads of symbols will be loaded. It's best to debug the other assemblies in their original solution.

[image: just my code]

Comment: That's too bad. I'll keep this post because in some cases it is relevant.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this, Start debugging, as soon as you've arrived at a breakpoint or used Debug > Break All. That's it

Comment: I don't get it. That just shows the Modules Window. Like I say, the referenced projects do not show up in this window. I need help finding out why.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. i just made an edit. Do check and let me know. :)